# How do deactive modal dialog by default in videojs?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video.js

I'm new in video.js. I use it in angular as follows:

**app.component.scss:**

```
@import "~video.js/src/css/video-js";
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<video id="video-id" class="video-js"></video>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   const player = videojs('video-id');
   player.ready(() => {
       player.src({
           src: 'http://localhost/stream/masterPlayList.m3u8',
           type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
       });

   });
}
```

but the result is as follow:
[image]

How can I remove extra sections(It marked with red)?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the player controls. The css is not imported if they appear like that. Try `@import "~video.js/src/css/video-js.css";`, with the extension.

Comment: The file is `scss` not `css`

Comment: @MortezaMalvandi... What happens if you try the suggestion anyway? SCSS is the same thing as CSS (just with extras added on).

Comment: @VC.one I Imported `video-js.scss` and if I change it to `video-js.css` occur error.